# List adapter doesn't update new items

Tags: android, listview, listadapter

Currently I have a ListView implemented with endless list loading, as in it'll load X number of items, then when the user scrolls to the bottom, it does an AsyncTask call to load more items, then loads them into the list and updates it. Currently this is all working, but the issue is that in order to get it working, it had to be done extremely inefficiently, to the point where as the list gets longer, it takes longer to load new items into it because the entire list is "replaced" each time, which obviously isn't desirable. Here is how I currently have the list updating from my AsyncTask after it gets a successful response:

```
//this first line is what makes the loading so slow, but without it the list returns an empty set when calling notifyDataSetChanged() on the ListAdapter
TopPostFragment.postList = new ArrayList<Post>(TopPostFragment.postList);
TopPostFragment.postList.addAll(result); //result is the new items that were received from the AsyncTask
TopPostFragment.updateList();
```

Obviously that first line is completely unnecessary, but for some reason if I delete it the list doesn't update correctly in the adapter, it will update to an empty list. My updateList() method in TopPostFragment is the following:

```
public static void updateList() 
    {   
        if(listAdapter != null)
        {
            listAdapter.clear();
            listAdapter.addAll(postList);
            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

I have a feeling the issue might somehow stem from how I am handling it in my listAdapter, so here is my constructor for that ListAdapter on how I am handling it:

```
List<Post> postList = null;

public PostListAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, List<Post> list, int whichList, int currentFeedID) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, list);
        postList = list;
    }
```

I've removed lines from all of the code here that have nothing to do with the issue. What is it I am doing wrong to where the list will only update if I copy it to a completely new list?

Comment: see those two gists for an efficient on demand Cursor: https://gist.github.com/pskink/b21c932f405740011144 and testing ContentProvider https://gist.github.com/pskink/9ab862cdd0d6b0281ab4

Answer (score 0):

It may be difficult to pinpoint the exact problem without being able to see a greater portion of the code. But as an example of a working implementation I have, you can check out how this works.

Generally as a rule of thumb though, I never initialize the list in the adapter to be set to any other list. Rather I always use .add() or .addAll() or .remove() or .clear() etc. to make sure that the reference to the original list is never lost, and you always have a handle to the same list the adapter and listview does.

So do a search through your code, and make sure that the list in the adapter is initialized one time, and only operated on and never set = to any other list.

```
public class ItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{

    private final static int VIEWTYPE_PIC = 1;
    private final static int VIEWTYPE_NOPIC = 0;

    private List<Item> items;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflator;
    ActivityMain activity;

    public ItemAdapter(List<Item> items, LayoutInflater layoutInflator, ActivityMain activity)
    {
        super();
        this.items = new ArrayList<Item>();
        updateItemList(items);
        this.layoutInflator = layoutInflator;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public void updateItemList(List<Item> updatedItems)
    {
        if (updatedItems != null && updatedItems.size() > 0)
        {
            // FIND ALL THE DUPLICATES AND UPDATE IF NESSICARY
            List<Item> nonDuplicateItems = new ArrayList<Item>();
            for (Item newItem : updatedItems)
            {
                boolean isDuplicate = false;
                for (Item oldItem : items)
                {
                    if (oldItem.getId().equals(newItem.getId()))
                    {
                        // IF IT IS A DUPLICATE, UPDATE THE EXISTING ONE
                        oldItem.update(newItem);
                        isDuplicate = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                // IF IT IS NOT A DUPLICATE, ADD IT TO THE NON-DUPLICATE LIST
                if (isDuplicate == false)
                {
                    nonDuplicateItems.add(newItem);
                }
            }

            // MERGE
            nonDuplicateItems.addAll(items);
            // SORT
            Collections.sort(nonDuplicateItems, new Item.ItemOrderComparator());
            // CLEAR
            this.items.clear();
            // ADD BACK IN
            this.items.addAll(nonDuplicateItems);
            // REFRESH
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    public void removeItem(Item item)
    {
        items.remove(item);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        if (items == null)
            return 0;
        else
            return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Item getItem(int position)
    {
        if (items == null || position > getCount())
            return null;
        else
            return items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return getItem(position).hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position)
    {
        Item item = getItem(position);
        if (item.getPhotoURL() != null && URLUtil.isValidUrl(item.getPhotoURL()) == true)
        {
            return VIEWTYPE_PIC;
        }
        return VIEWTYPE_NOPIC;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        ItemHolder itemHolder;
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            if (getItemViewType(position) == VIEWTYPE_PIC)
            {
                convertView = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.item_pic, null);
            } else
            {
                convertView = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
            }
                    // THIS CONSTRUCTOR ALSO CALLS REFRESH ON THE HOLDER FOR US
            itemHolder = new ItemHolder(convertView, position);
            convertView.setTag(itemHolder);
        } else
        {
            itemHolder = ((ItemHolder) convertView.getTag());
            itemHolder.refreshHolder(position);
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount()
    {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds()
    {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return (getCount() < 1);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled()
    {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Very interesting! I'll give this a shot, is there any reason you are using a BaseAdapter instead, and calling an empty super()? Could either of those things be my problem?

Comment: The super is out of habit, I think it would be inserted in or assumed by the compiler regardless (could be wrong). I am using BaseAdapter because for this case I have 2 different view types I am using, and because Just in case something needs to change, this way it will be much easier to do so later. But my main point here is that my list of items in the adapter is created one time in the constructor, and then never set again. only ever modified, and I make modify methods in the adapter for it. This has worked very well for me in all my apps so far :)

Comment: Also by AggieDev I hope you mean Texas A&M as that is the only true Aggie ;) lol

Comment: but again the key is the list that you are giving to ListAdapter, and making sure that you don't set the list in your code after you've given it to the adapter. However I have not had a lot of trouble shooting with ListAdapter itself as I always use BaseAdapter :(

Comment: Aggie indeed implies Texas A&M! I will give it a shot and report back on if this fixes the issue.

Comment: Alright sounds good :) don't copy mine exactly though cause I think you only need one view type in your adapter :/